# Javascript event handlers in Chrome would be executed in parallel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Javascript is single-threaded, that means all event handlers are executed without interrupts, all handlers are executed sequentially, one-by-one. That is true in all my previous experiences, until I encounter the following code snippets.

I write the following codes, and executed in **Chrome** (version 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit))

```
let port = chrome.runtime.connect("appid");
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg: string) {
    console.log("enter");
    for (let i = 0; i < 9999999; ++i) { }
    console.log("leave");
});
```

The other-side (corresponding to the appid) would send 2 messages through that port.

In normal execution (without setting breakpoint in Chrome devtools), the console output is:

```
enter
leave
enter
leave
```

that is perfect. However, if I set a breakpoint at console.log("enter"); in the Chrome devtools, the console output is:

```
enter
enter
leave
```

It seems that the Chrome does not stop at the breakpoint, still accepts the second message and run. Is there more than 1 thread in Chrome to handle Javascript events? And in which situation that I should consider the Javascript codes would not run sequentially?

Comment: I can't speak for what Chrome is doing at the breakpoint, but normal running of the code (without breakpoints) only ever has one thread processing events and only processes one event at a time.

Comment: issue is because of the breakpoint.

Comment: @Zig, could you give more detail about why the issue is because of the breakpoint? I could not find any documents describe this behavior. Thx.

Comment: its not documented but ive seen it before. most likely the reentry is recursive and not another thread. the breakpoint likely lets the "message pump" breathe.